# Android change color of a string without XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to change the color of the string "title" from a json object and put it in a listview with an array adapter without XML.

I have tried a lot of examples of stackoverflow, but I am not sure, if the array adapter, which I am using, is the right one.

When I was testing the examples I always became the same exception:

RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
public class TermineDetail extends ListActivity {

static JSONArray jArray;
static JSONObject jObject;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
static int clickedPosition;
static String title;

public void getJsonArrayAndClickedPosition(JSONArray array, int position) {
    this.jArray = array;
    this.clickedPosition = position;
    System.out.println("clickedPosition " + clickedPosition);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.listview_simple_layout, this.getJsonResource());

}

public ArrayList<String> getJsonResource() {

    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            if (i == clickedPosition) {
                jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                title = (String) jObject.get("title");

                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_simple_listview);
                tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your big island <b>ADVENTURE!</b>"));

                listItems.add("\n" + "\n" + jObject.getString("title")
                        + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "Datum: "
                        + jObject.getString("termin") + "\n" + "\n"
                        + "Uhrzeit: " + jObject.getString("time") + "\n"
                        + "\n" + "Beschreibung: "
                        + jObject.getString("text") + "\n" + "\n"
                        + "Location: " + jObject.getString("location")
                        + "\n" + "\n" + "Kontaktperson: "
                        + jObject.getString("contactperson") + "\n" + "\n"
                        + "Kontaktdaten: "
                        + jObject.getString("contactdata") + "\n" + "\n");

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listItems;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post some more information. e.g. the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your activity to your manifest file?

Comment: <activity android:name=".TermineDetail" android:label="@string/terminedetail_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.incomingandroid.TERMINEDETAIL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

Do you mean this?

Comment: yes. Is the TermineDetail class in a package? if so add the fully qualified name. otherwise try to remove the . before the class name.

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.incomingandroid.R.id.text_simple_listview);

I changed it to the full package path, but still the same error. Could it be the adapter?

Comment: But the problem is not the exception. Before i was trying to change the color, the Class was working fine.

Comment: ok, then you need to provide some more information, such as a logcat otherwise nobody will be able to help you (we can only guess, as i did :))

Comment: Ok, screenshot follows in a minute

Comment: you can also only copy the entries and post it here

Comment: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-21508031/logcat.png.html
Here is the Logcat-Screenshot

Comment: you get a NullPointerException at line 54. Can you point that line out?

Comment: tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your big island <b>ADVENTURE!</b>")); This is line 54

Comment: ahh ok now I get it what you want to do... :P why don't you want to create your own adapter?

Comment: Yeah, im a totally newbie in Android, how to realize it?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view the problem with your code is that you cannot access a TextView with the id R.id.text_simple_listview. you need to create a customer Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter (that will probably fit best your needs) and you need to create a custom view that is used for each entry.